# Is it possible to modify the linux assembler in order to modify what fuctions do?

Tags: assembly

I was wondering if it were possible to modify the linux assembler in order to change the function of "-" to "+" and vice versa.
I was also wondering if this would affect the whole system making it collapse. I apologize if this question is not appropriate here. Please explain why if it is the case.

E.g:
2+2 = 0
2-2 = 4

My objective is to see what applications this could have for a potential computer virus (I hope this is allowed here).

Comment: What do you mean by "change the function of - and +"?

Comment: The answer is anyway negative. You can change `as` all you like. This won't make any difference for existing executables.

Comment: I mean changing what they do: 2-2 = 4 2+2=0 ... I edited the question so it makes sense.

Comment: assemblers are just language translators to convert assembly code into machine code. You could modify the source of assembler to swap the role of `add` and `sub` mnemonics.

Comment: Would it affect the whole system?

Comment: I think you might be more likely to get helpful answers if you told us what problem you're actually facing.  Speculative questions like this seem unlikely to be useful to anyone else in the future, and you could answer it yourself by learning about how assemblers work.

Comment: To be honest, I hope this is allowed here, I was wondering what applications this could have for a computer virus: making the computer crash.

Comment: Not part of any *assembler*, but there has been [WCS: Writeable Control Store](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_store#Writable_stores).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is trivially possible, the fundamental flaw in your idea is that assemblers are not interpreters. Python programs are run by the Python interpreter, Swapping `-` and `+` in the Python interpreter would likely crash all Python programs. But normal programs are executed directly by the CPU. The assembler is not involved in their execution.

Comment: In that case, would there be any other alternative for doing what I mentioned before? I guess that if I changed the python interpreter, I could still crash the OS as there are a lot of python programs ...